# upload .tar.gz or .sql file from server to dropbox using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I want to upload my daily backup in the dropbox account. I used curl php for that and make one file with the code as below...

```
<?php
    $api_url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/home/DROP_BOX_FOLDER_NAME'; 
    $token = 'TOKEN'; 

    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
        'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
        'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.
        json_encode(
            array(
                "path"=> '23_10_2018--20_35_01.tar.gz',
                "mode" => "add",
                "autorename" => true,
                "mute" => false
            )
        )
    );
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $path = $filename;
    $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
    $filesize = filesize($path);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // debug

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo($response.'<br/>');
    echo($http_code.'<br/>');

    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The file with above code is in my server and my transfer file(.sql or .taz.gz) is also in my that server. 
when I run that file it does not generate any error but it does not transfer my files from the server to Dropbox.
I have dudes about $api_url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
$api_url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload'; 
//$api_url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/home/DROP_BOX_FOLDER_NAME'; 

$filename ='samples.tar.gz';

$token = 'MY TOKEN'; 

$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
    'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.
    json_encode(
        [
            "path"=> '/'.$filename,
            "mode" => "add",
            "autorename" => true,
            "mute" => false,
            "strict_conflict"=>false
        ]
    ),
    'data-binary @'.$filename
);
$ch = curl_init($api_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$path = $filename;
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
$filesize = filesize($path);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // debug

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo($response.'<br/>');
echo($http_code.'<br/>');

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: hello, 
shell_exec('curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
                         --header "Authorization: Bearer XYwIPjBaWjAAAAAAAAAANsxex4IFMoonomWoUKy1Wa3FEo0mwyOo3y********" \
                         --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\":\"/path/'.$fileName[1].'\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}" \
                         --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
                         --data-binary @local path);
but it does not work with php 5.6 version .
what should i do?

Comment: @LightLinkSolutions Could you please share the error you are getting?

Comment: no, it does not show any error but it does not transfer file to dropbox. because my server php version is 5.6 and above code only use with 5.5 version of php. so, what sholud i do for 5.6 in above code?

Comment: @LightLinkSolutions I have added an `ini_set('display_errors',1)` on the top of the script which will show error as it occurs, please try running the script with the updated code.

Comment: it does not show me error but it show 1 waring :  shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons ".

but in cpanel  /home/project_name/public_html/php.ini  i remove shell_exec() function only below function are present

disable_functions = exec,passthru,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

Comment: That simply means you need to enable shell_exec() from the CPanel or have to use some other alternative.

Comment: You need to confirm it with your hosting provider's customer support.